# Border-radius with division

Tags: html, css

I am having a hard time understanding [Mozilla's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) explanation of the border radius property when division is involved.

Example:

```
/* (first radius values) / top-left | top-right | bottom-right | bottom-left */
border-radius: 10px 5% / 20px 25em 30px 35em;
```

I know the first value `10px` is the width of the radius and `5%` is the height. I don't get how they are affected by the numbers following the `/`.

One sample: https://jsfiddle.net/wvyesszq/1/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can give every corner two values (so the maximum are 8 values) which is the radius in two directions (horizontal / vertical).

I think the following pictures explain it perfectly well:

[image]

The first set of values define the horizontal radius. And optionally the second set of values, preceded by a ‘/’ (it's not a divison), defines the vertical radius. **If only one set** of values are supplied, these are used for both the vertical and horizontal radius (what is apparently the reason of the confusion).

So, different from what you assumed – in your example the `10px` is the horizontal radius of the top-left-and-bottom-right. And the `5%` is the horizontal radius of the top-right-and-bottom-left. And the other four values after '/' are the vertical radii for top-left, top-right, bottom-right and bottom-left.

So remember: On both sites there are shorthands possible (before '/' and after), so you can really have everything between 2 and 8 values).

Check out the documentation of [border-radius](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-radius).